# cant access reactive form variable inside event function

Tags: angular, typescript

```
   class ComponentA { 
    int a = 15;
    int b = 30;
    chart: any = amChart(); //some library class obj
    function1() {
//this event call functionA() on every sppecific event
      this.chart.events.on("ready", functionA () {
                dateAxis.zoomToDates(
                  new Date(this.a),   <==== getting error this.a is undefined
                  new Date(this.b)
                );
              });}
    }
```

When I run the code

```
this.a is undefinded;
```

I have used VAR and public. (more specific a and b is reactive form variable)

Comment: Would you provide a bit more context for this question?  What is reactive?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind `this` or convert the function into arrow function

```
  class ComponentA { 
    int a = 15;
    int b = 30;
    chart: any = amChart(); //some library class obj
    function1() {
//this event call functionA() on every sppecific event
      this.chart.events.on("ready",  ()=> {
                dateAxis.zoomToDates(
                  new Date(this.a),   <==== getting error this.a is undefined
                  new Date(this.b)
                );
              });}
    }
```